# Instance Variable Being Reset in Java

Tags: java, arrays, instance-variables

I'm trying to make a program that reads a CSV file and then places the values read into a 2D double array.

The class called DataMatrix contains the 2D array as a private instance variable (at least I believe so). 
Now I would like to find the row average of this array but what I'm noticing, is that when I call the method for calculating the average the array is reset to it's default value.
I'm sure this is a beginner's mistake, but thank you in advanced for any assistance.

Here is the DataMatrix class:

```
public class DataMatrix{

private String rawInput;
private double[][] finalArr;
private String[] rows;
private String[][] arr;

public DataMatrix(){
    rawInput = "";
    rows = new String [1];
    arr = new String [1][1];
    finalArr = new double[arr.length][arr[0].length];
}

public void setInput(String input){
    rawInput = input;
}

public void setDoubleArray(){
    rows = rawInput.split("\n");
    arr = new String [rows.length][];

//Temporarly hold the values in the enhanced for loop, and re-split into the 2D array
int counter = 0;
for(String rowData: rows){
    arr[counter] = rowData.split(",");
    counter++;
}

//Convert the string to a double
double[][] finalArr = new double[arr.length][arr[0].length];

for (int i = 0; i < arr[0].length; i++){
    finalArr[0][i] = Double.valueOf(arr[0][i]);
}
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
    finalArr[i][0] = Double.valueOf(arr[i][0]);
}
//Debug
System.out.println(finalArr[0][0]+ " Size: "+ finalArr.length);
}

public double calcRowAvg(){
    //Debug
    System.out.println(finalArr[0][0] + " Size: "+ finalArr.length);
    return 0;
}
```

And here is the main class:

```
public class DataRun{
public static void main(String[] args){

    //Make sure the user passed the command line argument
    if (args.length != 1){
        System.out.println("Assignment1 takes exactly one command-line argument.");
        System.out.println("Usage: java Assignment1 some_file.csv");
        System.exit(0);
    }

    //Set filename to arguement
    String csvFileName = args[0];

    //Instantiate file reader
    CSVReader fileReader = new CSVReader();

    //Read the file into a string
    String text = fileReader.readFile(csvFileName);

    //Start array processing
    DataMatrix CSVCalc = new DataMatrix();

    CSVCalc.setInput(text);
    CSVCalc.setDoubleArray();

    double rowAvg = CSVCalc.calcRowAvg();
    double colAvg = CSVCalc.calcColAvg();

    System.out.println("Row: " + rowAvg + " Col: " + colAvg);
}
```

Sorry about the giant paste.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! It looks like you need to learn to use a debugger.  Please help yourself to some [complementary debugging techniques](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/).  If you still have issues afterwards, please feel free to come back with more details.

Comment: In the method `setDoubleArray` you have defined a local variable `finalArr` which hides the instance variable `finalArr` so any changes you make to the local `finalArr` are lost when `setDoubleArray` returns.

Comment: Jeez, sometimes things just stare me in the face, thanks for the assistance